# 'rowSelectionChanged' not triggered on click of a row in angular ui-grid with 'enableRowHeaderSelection' enabled

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I have a UI grid with selection(checkbox) enabled. On click of a row, it should redirect to other window and on click of checkbox, row should be selected(All the selected rows are then used for performing certain action.) I used on 'rowSelectionChanged' method, but this is triggered only on click of checkbox and not on row click

Is there any event triggered when i click on the row, so that i can redirect when the event is triggered?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when using 'enableRowHeaderSelection', there will be no triggered events.

A possible workaround could be to set 'enableRowHeaderSelection' to false, and include a checkbox in the first cell of each row (using cellTemplate). That way you could have both: checkbox and triggered events.

Comment: By setting 'enableRowHeaderSelection' to false, the default methods provided by ui grid like, 'getSelectedRows', can't be used. Is there any other event to be triggered on click of row?

Comment: By setting 'enableFullRowSelection' to true, 'rowSelectionChanged' event is triggered both on click of row header and ui grid cell. This resolves my issue.